# How to hide jstree splitter?

Tags: javascript, html, splitter

I have a conditional display of panels in my application. The panels are separated by horizontal and vertical splitters. I would like to hide the horizontal splitter bar if I am hiding the panel below it.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this -

```html
<div id="myPanels" class="splitter">
  <div class="leftPane" style="width:30%">
    <div class="horizontalSplitter">
      <div id="topPane" style="overflow-y: scroll "></div>
      <div id="bottomPane"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightPane" id="rightPanel">
    <div class="splitter" id="splitterRight">
      <div class="leftPane" style="width:50%" id="hleftPanel">
      </div>
      <div class="rightPane" style="width:50%" id="hRightPanel">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
$("#myPanels").splitter();
```

In this case if someone wants to hide the horizontal `splitter` bar with the `#topPanel` the code will be:

```
$("#topPanel").hide();
$("#topPanel").next().hide();
```